# Is there a keyboard shortcut to minimize/maximize the ribbon in MS products?

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, microsoft-office

Is there a keyboard shortcut to minimize/maximize the ribbon in MS products?
I'd like to do this at least in MS Word 2007 and Outlook 2007

Comment: Windows, OS X, or other?

Comment: @Lukasa: Office 2007 only exists for Windows (the corresponding OS X release is Office 2008).

Comment: @grawity: That is totally right, and highly embarrassing. Excuse me while I go hide my head in the sand for a while. :P

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>F1</kbd>

See [Minimize the Ribbon - Microsoft Help](http://office.microsoft.com/en-au/access-help/minimize-the-ribbon-HA010166329.aspx)

> Applies to: Microsoft Office Access
>   2007, Excel 2007, Outlook 2007,
>   PowerPoint 2007, Word 2007

Comment: This also appears to work in Office 2010.

Comment: You're right. There is even a little, clickable arrow on the top right side.